# GORM not bootstrapping from JAR

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Replacing a persistence layer in legacy app with a JAR file using Spring, Hibernate and GORM.  Methods like `person.save()` work fine when running agains project with Gradle etc. in project.  However, after I build the fat jar and reference it with `-cp my-big-fat-gorm.jar` I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [blah.Person] was
>   used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a
>   test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.

Using Spring boot for Spring, Hibernate4 and GORM and build.gradle file show below...

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "blah.App"

jar {
    baseName = 'blah-gorm'
    version =  '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
    compile 'org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.7'
    runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.181'
}
```

Am I missing something in the JAR file creation that causes Spring boot to honor `@Entity` etc.?

Here is a GitHub project that illustrates this and should allow you to execute and see the same stuff I'm seeing.

https://github.com/twcrone/spring-gorm-jar

Comment: Could you raise an issue at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS and I will investigate and get back to you

Comment: Actually no don't create an issue I see the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the Spring Boot Gradle plugin installed so you're not actually creating a fat JAR you need to add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.1.0.M2'
        groovyVersion = '2.3.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

With this in place doing `gradle assemble` and then `java -jar ...` results in bootstrapping GORM correctly

Comment: Cool...gets me closer, now it is telling me I have a configuration problem and `Offending resource: Groovy`.

Comment: Okay `java -jar ...` works but future usage of this JAR will be from another project using the JAR as a resource, not running it directly.  `groovy -cp blah..jar test.groovy` has the above issue with `Offending resource:Groovy`.

Comment: Probably fair enough answer for bootstrapping.  I'll accept and post a new question about 'Offending resource.'  Thanks!